# Setting BrowserFileHandling programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to set all lists/libraries that has BrowserFileHandling set to strict to permissive. I had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbrowserfilehandling.aspx so I want check if status is 1 and set it to 0 but I can't get it to work.

With the code (example):

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
    foreach (SPWeb web in collWebsite)
    {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPListCollection collList = web.Lists;

                foreach (SPList oList in collList)
                {
                    oList.BrowserFileHandling = 0;

                    }
    }
```

I can set all list's browserfilehandling to permissive. But if I want to test and set all to strict again and change the 0 to 1 I get

```
"Cannot implicitily convert type int  to Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBrowserFileHandling"
```

Why can I set it to 0 but not to 1?

I wanted to do a check something like:

```
if(oList.BrowserFileHandling == 1)
{
   //set to 0
}
```

but it doesn't work, what do I need to do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I simply tried to parse it instead with oList.BrowserFileHandling = (SPBrowserFileHandling)1; and it works but is this really the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it either by using

```
oList.BrowserFileHandling = SPBrowserFileHandling.Permissive;
```

or

```
oList.BrowserFileHandling = SPBrowserFileHandling.Strict;
```

So change your codes to

```
if (oList.BrowserFileHandling == SPBrowserFileHandling.Permissive)
                {
                    oList.BrowserFileHandling = SPBrowserFileHandling.Strict;
                }
```